# Anisble running through playbook twice after all Virtual Machines are done building in Vagrant

Tags: ansible, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have a Vagrantfile that 100% works. The desired outcome is really straight forward. Spin up 8 Ubuntu 16.04 vm's then provision all the servers using an Ansible playbook. However, right at the very end it is doing something annoying, for some reason the playbook run's twice and I can not figure out why. Here is my Vagrantfile.

```
# This guide is optimized for Vagrant 1.7 and above.
# Although versions 1.6.x should behave very similarly, it is recommended
# to upgrade instead of disabling the requirement below.
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.7.0"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  N = 8
        (1..N).each do |hpc_id|
          config.vm.define "hpc#{hpc_id}" do |hpc|
            hpc.vm.hostname = "hpc#{hpc_id}"
            hpc.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.30.#{200+hpc_id}"
            hpc.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
            hpc.ssh.insert_key = false

            hpc.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
              vb.name = "hpc#{hpc_id}"
              vb.memory = 512
              vb.cpus = 1
              vb.gui = false

          if hpc_id == N
            hpc.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
              # Disable default limit to connect to all the hpcs
              ansible.limit = "all"
              ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
              ansible.become_user = "root"
              ansible.groups = {
                 "Slurm_Primary_Controller" => ["hpc1"],
                 "Slurm_Backup_Controller" => ["hpc2"],
                 "Slurm_Primary_Database" => ["hpc3"],
                 "Slurm_Backup_Database" => ["hpc4"],
                 "My_SQL_Database" => ["hpc5"],
                 "Slurm_Worker" => ["hpc6", "hpc7", "hpc8"],
              }
           end
         end
       end
     end
   end
end
```

Here is output of the ansible playbook run as follows. I have not included vagrant build output for brevity purposes as the virtual machines all come up without any problem. However, I can add that if needed.

```
    hpc8: Running ansible-playbook...

PLAY [hpc1] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:34:35 -0700 (0:00:00.106)       0:00:00.106 ***********
changed: [hpc1]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:35:08 -0700 (0:00:32.548)       0:00:32.654 ***********
ok: [hpc1]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:35:10 -0700 (0:00:01.934)       0:00:34.589 ***********
changed: [hpc1] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc2] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:35:24 -0700 (0:00:14.522)       0:00:49.111 ***********
changed: [hpc2]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:35:56 -0700 (0:00:32.010)       0:01:21.121 ***********
ok: [hpc2]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:35:57 -0700 (0:00:01.406)       0:01:22.528 ***********
changed: [hpc2] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc3] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:36:13 -0700 (0:00:15.293)       0:01:37.822 ***********
changed: [hpc3]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:36:44 -0700 (0:00:31.712)       0:02:09.535 ***********
ok: [hpc3]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:36:46 -0700 (0:00:01.873)       0:02:11.409 ***********
changed: [hpc3] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc4] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:37:01 -0700 (0:00:14.514)       0:02:25.923 ***********
changed: [hpc4]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:37:30 -0700 (0:00:29.562)       0:02:55.486 ***********
ok: [hpc4]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:37:32 -0700 (0:00:01.337)       0:02:56.824 ***********
changed: [hpc4] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc5] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:37:47 -0700 (0:00:14.825)       0:03:11.650 ***********
changed: [hpc5]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:38:16 -0700 (0:00:29.061)       0:03:40.712 ***********
ok: [hpc5]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:38:17 -0700 (0:00:01.376)       0:03:42.089 ***********
changed: [hpc5] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc6 hpc7 hpc8] **********************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:38:29 -0700 (0:00:11.708)       0:03:53.797 ***********
changed: [hpc8]
changed: [hpc7]
changed: [hpc6]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:39:56 -0700 (0:01:27.055)       0:05:20.852 ***********
ok: [hpc8]
ok: [hpc6]
ok: [hpc7]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:39:59 -0700 (0:00:02.874)       0:05:23.727 ***********
changed: [hpc8] => (item=[u'htop'])
changed: [hpc6] => (item=[u'htop'])
changed: [hpc7] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
hpc1                       : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc2                       : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc3                       : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc4                       : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc5                       : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc6                       : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc7                       : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc8                       : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0

Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:32 -0700 (0:00:33.328)       0:05:57.056 ***********
===============================================================================
install python2 for ansible -------------------------------------------- 87.06s
hosts-setup : install required package --------------------------------- 33.33s
install python2 for ansible -------------------------------------------- 32.55s
install python2 for ansible -------------------------------------------- 32.01s
install python2 for ansible -------------------------------------------- 31.71s
install python2 for ansible -------------------------------------------- 29.56s
install python2 for ansible -------------------------------------------- 29.06s
hosts-setup : install required package --------------------------------- 15.29s
hosts-setup : install required package --------------------------------- 14.83s
hosts-setup : install required package --------------------------------- 14.52s
hosts-setup : install required package --------------------------------- 14.51s
hosts-setup : install required package --------------------------------- 11.71s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 2.87s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 1.94s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 1.87s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 1.41s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 1.38s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 1.34s
==> hpc8: Running provisioner: ansible...
Vagrant has automatically selected the compatibility mode '2.0'
according to the Ansible version installed (2.5.3).

Alternatively, the compatibility mode can be specified in your Vagrantfile:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#compatibility_mode

    hpc8: Running ansible-playbook...

PLAY [hpc1] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:36 -0700 (0:00:00.106)       0:00:00.106 ***********
changed: [hpc1]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:37 -0700 (0:00:00.654)       0:00:00.761 ***********
ok: [hpc1]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:38 -0700 (0:00:01.135)       0:00:01.897 ***********
ok: [hpc1] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc2] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:39 -0700 (0:00:01.110)       0:00:03.007 ***********
changed: [hpc2]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:40 -0700 (0:00:00.690)       0:00:03.698 ***********
ok: [hpc2]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:41 -0700 (0:00:00.818)       0:00:04.516 ***********
ok: [hpc2] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc3] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:42 -0700 (0:00:00.960)       0:00:05.476 ***********
changed: [hpc3]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:43 -0700 (0:00:01.098)       0:00:06.574 ***********
ok: [hpc3]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:44 -0700 (0:00:00.849)       0:00:07.424 ***********
ok: [hpc3] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc4] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:45 -0700 (0:00:00.968)       0:00:08.392 ***********
changed: [hpc4]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:45 -0700 (0:00:00.615)       0:00:09.008 ***********
ok: [hpc4]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:46 -0700 (0:00:00.769)       0:00:09.777 ***********
ok: [hpc4] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc5] ********************************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:47 -0700 (0:00:00.993)       0:00:10.771 ***********
changed: [hpc5]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:48 -0700 (0:00:00.592)       0:00:11.363 ***********
ok: [hpc5]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:48 -0700 (0:00:00.802)       0:00:12.166 ***********
ok: [hpc5] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY [hpc6 hpc7 hpc8] **********************************************************

TASK [install python2 for ansible] *********************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:49 -0700 (0:00:00.864)       0:00:13.031 ***********
changed: [hpc6]
changed: [hpc7]
changed: [hpc8]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:49 -0700 (0:00:00.179)       0:00:13.210 ***********
ok: [hpc6]
ok: [hpc7]
ok: [hpc8]

TASK [hosts-setup : install required package] **********************************
Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:51 -0700 (0:00:01.498)       0:00:14.708 ***********
ok: [hpc6] => (item=[u'htop'])
ok: [hpc8] => (item=[u'htop'])
ok: [hpc7] => (item=[u'htop'])

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
hpc1                       : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc2                       : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc3                       : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc4                       : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc5                       : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc6                       : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc7                       : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
hpc8                       : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

Friday 22 June 2018  13:40:52 -0700 (0:00:01.522)       0:00:16.231 ***********
===============================================================================
hosts-setup : install required package ---------------------------------- 1.52s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 1.50s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 1.14s
hosts-setup : install required package ---------------------------------- 1.11s
install python2 for ansible --------------------------------------------- 1.10s
hosts-setup : install required package ---------------------------------- 0.99s
hosts-setup : install required package ---------------------------------- 0.97s
hosts-setup : install required package ---------------------------------- 0.96s
hosts-setup : install required package ---------------------------------- 0.86s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 0.85s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 0.82s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 0.80s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 0.77s
install python2 for ansible --------------------------------------------- 0.69s
install python2 for ansible --------------------------------------------- 0.65s
install python2 for ansible --------------------------------------------- 0.62s
install python2 for ansible --------------------------------------------- 0.59s
install python2 for ansible --------------------------------------------- 0.18s
```

If you want to run the whole the thing for yourself from start to finish I have it posted on Github. I have not finished building the Ansible playbook yet so the project is obviously incomplete.

[Github Code](https://github.com/scottsisco/vagrant-ansible-stackoverflow-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Here is the correct code. I needed to close the provider section with an `end` before moving into the provision section.

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.7.0"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    N = 8
    (1..N).each do |hpc_id|
      config.vm.define "hpc#{hpc_id}" do |hpc|
        hpc.vm.hostname = "hpc#{hpc_id}"
        hpc.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.30.#{200+hpc_id}"
        hpc.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
        hpc.ssh.insert_key = false
        hpc.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
          vb.name = "hpc#{hpc_id}"
          vb.memory = 512
          vb.cpus = 1
          vb.gui = false
        end

      if hpc_id == N
        hpc.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
          # Disable default limit to connect to all the hpcs
          ansible.limit = "all"
          ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
          ansible.become_user = "root"
          ansible.groups = {
             "Slurm_Primary_Controller" => ["hpc1"],
             "Slurm_Backup_Controller" => ["hpc2"],
             "Slurm_Primary_Database" => ["hpc3"],
             "Slurm_Backup_Database" => ["hpc4"],
             "My_SQL_Database" => ["hpc5"],
             "Slurm_Worker" => ["hpc6", "hpc7", "hpc8"],
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How is that different from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50999173/2947502)?

Comment: Not different. Just more explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Remove `hpc.vm.provision` out of `hpc.vm.provider`.

---

<sup>There are reasons to properly format and indent your code.</sup>